# How to change a ProgressBar value using a TextBox

Tags: c#, vb.net

I've been messing around with a `ProgressBar` and I wondered how to change the value of a `ProgressBar` using a `TextBox`. So if you type a value in a `TextBox` from 0 to 99 and then press enter, the value of the `ProgressBar` changes to the value you typed in.

How can I do this? VS says that `TextBox1.Text` cannot be used as a method.

This is the code I currently have:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = textBox1.Text();
        }
```

I've tried this (which didn't work):

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        i = 1;
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = textBox1.Text();
        }
```

In VB.NET I just type the following code and then it would work:

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        ProgressBar1.Value = Val(TextBox1.Text)
End If
```

Does anyone knows how I can fix this? Also, how can I say in c# `val(something)`?

Is it possible to use the same code I used in VB.NET in C#?

Comment: Use `textBox1.Text;` instead of `textBox1.Text()`

Comment: Remove Parenthesis after Text: textBox1.Text;

Comment: Why do you have to write this code in two languages?

Comment: @LarsTech I used to code in vb.net but switched to c#.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is not a method, but a property! So just

```
progressBar1.Value = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);
```

Method connected with class:

```
objectOfSomeClass.MethodName();
```

Property of class:

```
objectOfSomeClass.propertyName;
```

Important things to know:
When you move mouse over variable you'll see type of this element. I gues you know what types are if you got so far :)
Each object can have properties and methods. Like textbox have string property called "Text". Object can also contain a method. To use a method you need brackets, because some of them may handle parameters :)
Second Question:
Add this to your form (the place where you define events like button_click):

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.keyCode == ...
}
```

check this
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tryied that too but then `textBox.Text` gets a red line and it says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' ".

Comment: try now, I added parsing method

Comment: Thank you it worked, but do you have an answer for my second question?

Comment: actually I have :) check my new answer.

Comment: Usefull but not an answer for my second question. My question was how to say val(label1.text) or val(textbox1.text) or whatever like that in c#.

Comment: well it's quite simple. val(something) is equivelent of parsing. So if it's string with possible numbers you can check how to use Int32.Parse() or, safer, Int32.TryParse(). Otherwise, if you have number to be read you convert it by something.toString(). However in general THERE IS NO METHOD SMART ENAUGHT, in c#, TO COMPETE WITH VAL(). http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/36064-val-replacement/

Comment: @Emre stuff like that you can whack into Google to get answers on. Simply put, use `.TryParse`. I wouldn't bother with `Val`, even in VB.

Comment: So in that case, I need to work with parse? Also, while I was looking for a replacement for val(), I found the following code that also worked for my situation for the progressbar:  progressBar1.Value = Convert.ToByte(textBox1.Text);

Comment: Yes, you have to parse values and there is no other option. About your new solution, remember that progressBar.Value property is int type, so it might cause misunderstanding. Furthermore byte is the way "shorter" than int is, so the conversion might be not possible in some situations. Int is safer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = i;
        }
```

remove text1.text and put i. your problem will solve.

Comment: The red line disapeared and I thought for a second it was solved untill I tryied to type something in the textbox. The application stops and visual studio goes to ` int i = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);`

Comment: `int i = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text());` change it this way

Comment: Nope, still gives an error. Text cannot be used as a method.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);` I also don't think you need `i = 1`.

Comment: Like @Bugs say, remove the parentheses again and _**don't**_ set `i` to 1. Doing `i = 1` will just override whatever the result of `textBox1` is every time.